# How to set default SIM for calls on Lenovo A7000?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sim-card, lenovo

How to set default SIM for calls on Lenovo A7000 running Android Lollipop 5.0 and Lenovo's Vibe UI?

PS: I have bought an Android phone for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting can be found in :

Settings->SIM Management

Answer (score 0):

Open Stock dialer → Select the options from top right (Action overflow button - 3 dots after the voice search assistant).

Select *Settings* → *Call Settings* → *Phone Account Settings* → *Make calls with*.

Here you can select 3 options. If you select **Ask first** - you'll be prompted every-time you make a call, to select from which sim you want to make the call.
Or select either of the *SIM*s directly (using 2nd and 3rd options).